# How do I match the design of an element my plugin adds to WordPress with the current active website theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new in WordPress plugin development and I'm really insecure about how to match the design of an element that my custom plugin adds into the DOM with the current active theme of the WordPress website. How do I know if the theme has any preset colors and not using WordPress ones and do I actually have to be worried about my element colors not matching the current active theme? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is very common when we introduce content into existing Dom from theme. But you can do following to avoid issues.

1. Add class prefixes. You can add prefixes to your element classes like "plgName-". This will avoid css overwrite with existing theme css.
2. Always queue and load your stylesheets after theme using wp_enqueue_scripts with proper priority.
3. Test with major theme frameworks, like gutenberg blocks, elementor, divi, beaver, wpbakery etc.

Good luck with your plugin development.

Comment: I'm afraid you do not understand what my question is. Thanks for your suggestions but I'm not afraid I do not know how to apply my custom plugin CSS, I'm afraid I don't know how to match the custom plugin element stylization colors with the current WordPress theme colors. How do I get the current theme primary color, current theme secondary color inside my style.css file? As far as I know many themes are using default WP preset colors, but some aren't. How do I know inside my custom plugin CSS file when a theme is using the default WP colors or not?

Comment: I am sorry i though you were asking about loading css stylesheet. Now I understand your question. I think good approach would be checking if css file of default theme filename is present or loaded in wp styles array. Using function in this answer might help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121273/how-to-check-if-a-stylesheet-is-already-loaded

Comment: I think you can also read default colors value using get_user_option https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127401/get-current-active-wp-color-scheme

Comment: Still not answering my question to be honest. How do I enqueue my custom plugin stylesheet and inside it (the css file) use current theme color variables?